# How to chain jobs in Dagster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jobs, job-scheduling, dagster

I need to chain several jobs. Some have to be started right after other have finished and some need results of other jobs as an input.

Seems that I can start one job after the other by using sensors. AI suggests using `@solid` and `@pipeline` decorators, but I was unable to find suitable example of their usage in Dagster documentation or the internet. I can't figure out how to pass output from one job to the other. `job_3(job_2())` call doesn't seem like a Dagster approach, isn't it?

Here is the code to illustrate an issue:

```py
@job
def job_1():
    save_to_db_op(
        make_api_call_op()
    )

@job
def job_2():
    out_1, out_2 = process_data_op(
        make_another_api_call_op()
    )
    save_to_db_op(out_1)
    return out_2  # I need to pass it to another job


@job
def job_3(out_2): # how to pass input here?
   process_op(out_2)
   do_some_other_staff_op()


# this function is a pseudocode to represent what I want to recreate in Dagster
def figure_it_out_pipeline():
   job_1() # wait until complete
   job_3(
       job_2
   )
```

Comment: To chain jobs, you'd have to use `op graphs`  https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/graphs. With graphs, you can build graphs and use them in jobs.  https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/assets/graph-backed-assets

Another option is you can define multiple jobs and use run sensors to trigger the other dependent jobs.
I suggest you go with the `assets` pattern. `@solids` and `@pipelines` are deprecated in favour of `@assets`, `@ops` and `@jobs`.